# Output voltage approximation in Wheatstone bridge

Tags: wheatstone-bridge

[image]

When I calculate the potential difference in the above circuit, I find:

v1 = Ug*(ΔR+R)/(2R+ΔR)

v2 = Ug*(R)/(2R+ΔR)

Uo = ΔU = v1-v2

ΔU = Ug*[ΔR/(2R+ΔR)]

But it is always approximated to:

ΔU = Ug*ΔR/2R

Another example of this kind of approximation can be found [here](http://fab.cba.mit.edu/classes/4.140/section.Architecture/people/Ge/KarlHoffmann.pdf).
[image]

What makes this approximation mathematically valid?
Is it the derivative?
If we ignore ΔR and not ignore and plot the expressions we see that they get so close for small values of ΔR:

[image]

I just cannot show it mathematically.

Comment: The text doesn't relate to the diagram. But, basically, if you add small to big you can often ignore small.

Comment: They are two different sources/texts. But both do the same approximation. I cant get how they approximate it

Comment: If I ignore ΔR in that equation the equation becomes zero.  they ignore the one in denominator only strange

Comment: You can only ignore \$\small \Delta R\$ when it's added or subtracted to/from \$\small R\$ or something larger. e.g. \$\frac{0.1}{100+0.1}\approx\frac{0.1}{100}\$. This  doesn't work when multiplying or dividing.

Comment: cant we prove it mathematically? using limit theorem or else

Comment: It doesn't really need proving; if you add a small value to a much larger value the answer can often be taken as the much larger value. It does, however, depend on circumstances - particularly, how accurate you want the answer to be.

Comment: I see what you mean see my edit, I just wanted to show somehow mathematically. Maybe I should take the difference [ΔR/(2R+ΔR)] - [ΔR/(2R)] and show that for lim ΔR-->0 the difference goes to zero

Comment: Yes, that's the correct approach.